# Nested stream to check the truth condition at first instance

Tags: java, stream

Lets say I have  `Car`s with `Feature`s, and I have been given a `List` of features to look for in the `Car`s available with me. Though I could have done that using for-loop, what are the suggestions for below? Is this production-worthy?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;

public class LookupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Feature ft11 = new Feature(1);
        Feature ft12 = new Feature(2);
        Feature ft13 = new Feature(4);
        Car fer = new Car("Ferrari", ft11, ft12, ft13);

        Feature ft21 = new Feature(1);
        Feature ft22 = new Feature(2);
        Feature ft23 = new Feature(8);
        Car suz = new Car("Suzuki", ft21, ft22, ft23);

        List<Car> cars = Arrays.asList(fer, suz);
        List<Integer> lookForTypes = Arrays.asList(4); // look whether any car has feature-type 4

        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(lookForTypes)) {
            /* code block in question : start */
            boolean atLeastOneTypeFound = cars
                    .parallelStream()
                    .anyMatch(holding -> holding.getAmounts()
                            .parallelStream()
                            .anyMatch(feature -> {
                                return lookForTypes.contains(feature.type);
                            }));
            /* code block in question : end */    
            System.out.println("atLeastOneTypeFound=" + atLeastOneTypeFound);
        }
    }
}

class Car {
    List<Feature> featureList;
    String name;

    public Car(String name, Feature... features) {
        featureList = Arrays.asList(features);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Feature> getAmounts() {
        return featureList;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Feature {
    int type;

    public Feature(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Ok, that was a typo actually.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the `Car`, you can also flatMap to have the features and then distinct them before searching.

```
cars.stream()
  .flatMap(car -> car.getAmounts().stream())
  .map(Feature::getType)
  .distinct() // As spotted by @Pimgd in the comments this is useless
  .anyMatch(lookForTypes::contains);
```

But if you want to improve the readability of your code you should better consider to move a part of this "logic" into your objects :

```
cars.stream()
  .anyMatch(car -> car.hasAtLeastOneFeature(lookForTypes);

// ...

Car {
  boolean hasAtLeastOneFeature(List<Integer> features) {
    // Note that I renamed getAmounts to getFeatures
    return getFeatures().stream()
      .anyMatch(feature -> features.contains(feature.getType());
  }
}
```

Comment: Why distinct before searching? ``anyMatch`` would stop upon finding a hit, so what's the point in making a list of uniques first?

Comment: What is the difference between doing `.parallelStream().anyMatch()` and your `flatMap(stream) -> map() -> anyMatch()` implementation? I dont need the `Car`.

Comment: @Pimgd indeed, there is no gain to `distinct` first. @xploreraj using `flatMap` you avoid the nested `Stream<Stream>` so that your code is a bit more readable.

Comment: @gervais.b But is it not like `stream` as opposed to `parallelStream` ?

Comment: You can use `flatMap` on with `stream` and `parallelStream` without changes. I used `stream` in my sample because the word is shorter.